# What is Linux for the MS-DOS tree command?

Tags: linux, command-line

What is Linux for the MS-DOS tree command?

tree

List a tree listing of the current drive. Below is a basic example of what a directory may look like.

```
C:.
├───Common
├───Director
├───Flash
├───Shockwave 8
│ ├───DswMedia
│ ├───Prefs
│ └───Xtras
└───update
```

Comment: "find" isn't that far off...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is also a Linux command `tree`. But it doesn't always come pre installed.

If you are using Ubuntu (or a Debian based distro) you can install the tree command by typing

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

Or for other distros or if you want the source code, you can check out the [Tree homepage](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/)

[If you're interested, it's written by a guy called Steve Baker and his site is [here](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/)]